# '3-50-2014' is '3-2-2018' for Java?

Tags: java

I was trying to use the `SimpleDateFormat` to parse some date string, and I notice this ridiculous incident.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("d-M-yyyy");
Date d = sdf.parse("3-50-2014");
```

Instead of giving me an error, it returns '3-2-2018' normally...How could this happen? How to avoid this?

Comment: Well, start at January 2014 and add 49 months -- you get February 2018.  (Months start at 1, hence 49 not 50.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is because the `SimpleDateFormat` is in lenient mode: it forgives "small" issues, such as setting the months too high, adjusting the year instead. For example, in your case it interprets the additional 48 months as four years.

Calling `sdf.setLenient(false)` will fix this problem.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/MDX9DF)

Comment: thanks a lot. I cannot believe they set this to *true* by default.

Answer (score 1):

> How to avoid this?

Use a better date-time library.

That means either:

- [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)
- The [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html)

  - Bundled with [Java 8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8_.28March_18.2C_2014.29)
  - Inspired by Joda-Time but re-architected
  - Defined by [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310)

## Joda-Time

Using Joda-Time 2.4.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "d-M-yyyy" );
DateTime dateTime = formatter.parseDateTime( "3-50-2014" ); // Note the invalid month number.
```

When run, we get an Exception thrown (as expected).

```
Exception in thread "main" org.joda.time.IllegalFieldValueException: Cannot parse "3-50-2014": Value 50 for monthOfYear must be in the range [1,12]
```